# Hack to change data source of a layer file in ArcGIS 9.3.1 with python?

Tags: python, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3, layers

I'm looking for a way to change the source of my layer file using python. Actually I want to do this because I need to re-use a XSL template which is defined under the tap `HTML popup` of the layer properties dialog. As I can't use the `MakeFeatureLayer_management`- command to create a layer file that contains the `HTML popup` information I'm aiming at letting the layer file point to a different data source every time my python code is being executed. I know it is a breeze using `arcpy` but I'm bound to use the `gp`-object. This there a workaround anyone knows of?